# Can I use dagger stealth multiplier on a dragon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Lately, I've been playing as assassin with a pair of daggers, taking advantage of my x30 damage multiplier from a stealth hit and 100 stealth skill. But unfortunately, when the dragon decides to land, I'm always already discovered and have to fight him in plain sight, which results in very hard fights and a lot of empty healing potions.

Is there a way for me to effectively backstab a dragon?

Comment: Maybe in a city when NPCs distract the dragon? Only way I can really think of (And maybe bow and arrow when it's flying).

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can backstab them, and with the right equipment you can kill a dragon in a single hit.

Stealthing a dragon is difficult if it has already found you and is in battle -- I personally haven't discovered a way to do this. But dragons that sit on word walls can be snuck up on and then stabbed fairly easily.

If a dragons spots you, I would recommend going invisible or hiding until the dragon stops looking for you and then proceeding with sneaking up and stabbing it when it lands.

If you want to see a Stealth dragon kill in action check out [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7fA43G8JPo).

Comment: thats so epic!!

Comment: I just happened upon this exact spot (because I was doing a quest that takes you just a few feet away) and recognized it from that video and tried it. I'm lvl. 57, so it was an Ancient Dragon, and the difficulty was on Adept. Two Ebony daggers ("Epic" from ~160 Smithing with gear) one with "Inferno" (30 fire damage). It took two stealthed two hand power attacks to kill him. The first time the corpse just disappeared (no soul!) but luckily I'd saved and the second time the corpse stayed and I got my soul.

Comment: @agf xD yeah dragons souls a bit glitchy.

Comment: If you've maxed-out your Sneak skill and can't slip up to the dragon undetected, you can still use the Shadow Warrior perk to get a sneak attack on it mid-battle.