# Sneaking against dragons

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use dagger stealth multiplier on a dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39509/can-i-use-dagger-stealth-multiplier-on-a-dragon)

Is it possible to land a successful sneak attack on dragons?
This is what I do against normal enemies - run up to them, and at the last moment, I crouch, activating Shadow Warrior, and hit them for x30 damage. If I use Slow Time/Dragonrend in conjunction with this technique against dragons, will it work?

Comment: Are you talking about sneak attacks in general or just the specific combination you just mentioned? cause I find that would be really hard to do in the short time you have before a dragon notices you.

Answer (score 0):

This *does* work, but like all applications of the Shadow Warrior "glitch" this isn't 100% reliable.  The [Sneak page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_(Skyrim)) on the Skyrim Wikia mentions this, and there are other reports around the 'net of people pulling it off.

However, given that you're going to be up against a dragon, you should plan on being able to tank it at least a little bit - their attacks are continuous for a few seconds, unlike most other enemies.  You're going to soak up a bit of damage, even if you're only detected for a short while between Shadow Warrior activations.

Personally, though, I'd probably go for power attacks and speed rather than trying to use Shadow Warrior - I never really had a problem against dragons with a combination of Dragonrend, dual wielded enchanted daggers, and power attacks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question, yes, it is possible to sneak-attack a dragon; as far as the mechanics of sneak attacks and detection go, dragons are much like any other enemy.

There's plenty of evidence that sneak attacks, in general, work against dragons, including [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39509/can-i-use-dagger-stealth-multiplier-on-a-dragon) with video evidence. I can also confirm that dragons that lose track of you will stop looking and allow you to return to "undetected" state after a while, so Shadow Warrior will work *in theory*.

However, I have not tried the specific combination you mentioned, so I'm not positive how effective it will be. Dragons appear to be very good at sensing enemies behind them when they are looking. Shadow Warrior works best against enemies that you are not very close to or that you're hidden from: it makes them lose track of where you are even if they used to know, but if they can still see you, it isn't nearly as effective. You will probably have to get the timing very precise to be effective.